# SQL Date Subtraction Between Two Years

Tags: sql-server, date, subtraction

I am having an issue with a query I am trying to convert from MS Access. The query flags record for removal when it is older than 90 days but when I convert this query to sql server is is removing too many records.

```
UPDATE  DT.SM_T_CountTotals
       SET  IsActive = 0
WHERE Convert(varchar, DT.SM_T_CountTotals.PostDate, 101) <
        Convert(varchar, GetDate()- 90, 101)
```

When I run this query in MS Access I get a total of 3793 records that are flagged but in SQL server I get 69061 records that are flagged for removal.  The GetDate()-90 value is correct at 10/26/2010 but it is flagging everything from this year to be removed.

I am sure it is something easy that I am overlooking. Help please?

I figured it out:

```
UPDATE  DT.SM_T_CountTotals
   SET  IsActive = 0
WHERE DT.SM_T_CountTotals.PostDate < Convert(varchar, GetDate()- 90, 101)
```

Comment: What's the type of the `DT.SM_T_CountTotals.PostDate` column?

Comment: Try not to use Convert like this in your WHERE clause as it will not allow your query to use the index properly. I suggest you rephrase this to use between. I am assuming that DT.SM_T_CountTotals is in fact a DateTime.

Comment: I should make note it is this: Convert(varchar, DT.SM_T_CountTotals.PostDate, 101) that will cause the issues using any indexes as it will have to perform a fulll table scan to do the conversion.

Comment: Converting to String and doing a comparision will land you in trouble sooner or later. Check out my answer for a better way of comparing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing VARCHAR values, not DATEs.

101 converts to MM/DD/YY, so you're comparing month, then day, then year.

You should be using 112 (yymmdd)

Comment: Which is another reason why I suggest the BETWEEN in the WHERE. Seems silly to convert a datetime just to compare based on dates.

Comment: @Robert I can't see why you suggest BETWEEN when the OP's test is strictly less than. I can't see why you add this comment to my reply either.

Comment: Because calculation like this can be done via the the datetime data type which would not cause a fulltable scan and would not incur the additional overhead of a CONVERT or CAST. Or have I been reading Itzik Ben-Gan's articles on effective temporal queries improperly?

Comment: @robert The OP wants records where postdate < today-90. I just can't see how a BETWEEN clause could be germane to his request

Comment: WHERE DT.SM_T_CountTotals.PostDate BETWEEN DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()), 0)-90 AND DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0,getdate()), 0) If you perform any manipulation on a column from table(s) you are selecting from you will not be able to use the indexes properly. While this may not be a big deal in an app using Access it can be in very large DBs.

Comment: Notice that while I am converting the getdate() values in my where clause I am not doing it on every single entry in the table - it happens only once when the query is intially run. So I am saving overhead on not casting/ormanipulating every row and I am also getting the ability to use indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Calculations between two dates can be easily done in the native data type rather than convert it to string. One can (and you have) get incorrect answers from such conversions.

Use `DateDiff` in the where clause to get the records that are more than 90 days old.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

```
UPDATE  DT.SM_T_CountTotals
SET  IsActive = 0
WHERE ABS (DATEDIFF (dd, Getdate(), DT.SM_T_CountTotals.PostDate)) > 90
```